# check whether the android patch is applied

Tags: android, git, patch

we usually use git am or git apply to apply patches, sometimes the patch file is too  much, so I want to use a shell scrip to apply all of them, but how can we check whether it is applied by a Script(python or shell)

```
#git apply --check can not help me.
```

Comment: Why `git apply --check` can not help you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `git am -q`, it will only print error messages. So, read the output to check whether it is applied in script.

Comment: it also can not help me. I have solved it now by check Whether each line in patch file is joined. this may be a stupid method.